# Jetpack Compose Navigation: Showing multipled bottomsheets on top of each other

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm trying to find a solution for displaying multiple bottom sheets on top of each other to accomodate our UX/Design.

Currently been trying with [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist) and [Compose Navigation Reimagined](https://github.com/olshevski/compose-navigation-reimagined), but to no avail. Seems like the built inner workings of BottomSheets are to only be displayed on at a time, as in displaying one sheet, hide it and swap content and display the "new sheet".

Issue could be somewhat related to [this github issue on accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1317#issuecomment-1453376672)

Essentially what i'm trying to do is being able to have a "stack" of bottomsheets on top of each other.
I've been trying to make things work with the compose navigation, but having issues with background colors and replicating the "bottom sheet" overlay when the screen enters.

Any one who has found a way to implement something along the lines of what i'm trying?